# Unexpected token '<newline>' after a statement in an if block

Tags: python, newline, code-formatting

I am new to Python and could use some help with this below code

```
def find_letter_in_alphabet (letter):
    i = 0
    for current_letter in range(len(alphabet)):
        if letter != current_letter : i++
    return I
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the Python tools that come with that. I am given the error 
    `Unexpected token '<newline>'`
after the
`if letter != current_letter : i++`

I am used to writing in  c# so python is a pretty big change for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to indent the body of the `if`. Also, you should change `I` to `i` and change `i++` to `i += 1` because Python doesn't have a `++` operator:

```
def find_letter_in_alphabet(letter):
    i = 0
    for current_letter in range(len(alphabet)):
        if letter != current_letter:
            i += 1
    return i
```

In Python, whitespace matters for syntax, unlike in C#. You must add a newline and indent every block in Python (if the block is more than one statement).

Comment: If the body of the `if` contains only one statement, you don't need to indent it.  It's perfectly valid to have the `i += 1` on the same line as the `if`.

Comment: Thank you! Old habits die hard I guess!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `i++`. In Python there is no `++`.
You can add one and assign it to the same variable.

```
i = i + 1
```

or in a more pythonic way:

```
i += 1
```

You can do the if in a single line like this:

```
if letter != current_letter: i += 1
```

but there is a simpler code if you put a line break after `:` (with the corresponding indentation):

```
if letter != current_letter: 
   i += 1
```

Also: be careful that you are returned `I` (in capital letters) and not `i`.

Comment: The capitalized I was just a formatting thing with SO. Thank you for your help though! My C# kicked in with the I++